# Print command is spamming until I stop it

Tags: python-3.x

SO whenever I run this it'll say "Say something (or type bye to quit" and whenever I type something it'll spam it (example: if I type "music" it'll spam "music is so relaxing!" over and over until I stop it)

```
greetings = ["Hello!", "What's up?!", "Howdy!", "Greetings!"]
goodbyes = ["Bye!", "Goodbye!", "See you later!", "See you soon!"]

keywords = ["music", "pet", "book", "game"]
responses = ["Music is so relaxing!", "Dogs are man's best friend!", "I know a lot of books.", "I like to play video games."]
import random
print(random.choice(greetings))

user = input("Say something (or type bye to quit): ")
user = user.lower()
while (user != "bye"):
    for index in range(len(keywords)):
        if (keywords[index] in user):
            print("Bot: " + responses[index])   

while (user != "bye"):
    keyword_found = False

    for index in range(len(keywords)):
        if (keywords[index] in user):
            print("Bot: " + responses[index])
            keyword_found = True

    if (keyword_found == False):
        new_keyword = input("I'm not sure how to respond. What keyword should I respond to? ")
        keywords.append(new_keyword)
        new_response = input("How should I respond to " + new_keyword + "? ")
        responses.append(new_response)

    user = input("Say something (or type bye to quit): ")
    user = user.lower()

print(random.choice(goodbyes))
```

Also whenever I typed a new keyword it would just freeze so idk what's wrong with this

btw this script isn't original

Answer (score 1):

```
user = input("Say something (or type bye to quit): ")
user = user.lower()
while (user != "bye"):
    for index in range(len(keywords)):
        if (keywords[index] in user):
            print("Bot: " + responses[index])
```

The variable `user` does not change inside of this loop, so the `while` condition is always true, and it runs forever.

You need to add an input statement **inside** the loop.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused on what to do
(I'm pretty new to python)